React native (Expo) stripe connect redirect_url
My tech stack includes Expo React native, supabase and stripe
I have created an edge function like so with a HTTPS redirect URL
Deno.serve(async (req) => {
  // * I want to create the stripe account.
  const data = await req.json();

  // Initialise the stripe sdk
  const stripeKey = Deno.env.get("EXPO_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SK_TEST");
  const stripeClient = stripe(stripeKey);

  const accountLink = await stripeClient.accountLinks.create({
    account: data.body,
    refresh_url: "https://bulkapp.com/reauth",
    return_url: "https://bulkapp.com/return",
    type: "account_onboarding",
  });

  return new Response(
    JSON.stringify(accountLink),
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } },
  );
});

I am wondering after the user completes their session
which I call using this.
// Create the account link

const linkedStripe = await edgeFunction("stripe-link", user.id, createStripe.data.id);
if (linkedStripe.error) throw new Error(linkedStripe.error.message);
const stripeUrl = linkedStripe.data.url;
let webData = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(stripeUrl);

I want the finished session to redirect back to the application.
After some searching on google I have a heard and a mix of the use of Deeplinks (universal links) but I have not seen proper implementation on how to include this. Has anyone done this before?

What I've done and that works is you make your server 'return' URL 3xx redirect to something like my-app://onboarding-complete, and you setup deep links(as you say) so that your app can intercept those and present whatever UI it needs.

The first step really is setting up a deep/universal link and testing that in isolation it can work and be detected in your app(should be lots of info on this online), and then you can integrate that as the Stripe return URL
